# Split NSString into words, then rejoin it into original form

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I am splitting an NSString like this: (filter string is an nsstring)

```
seperatorSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    [seperatorSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];
NSMutableArray *words = [[filterString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:seperatorSet] mutableCopy];
```

I want to put words back into the form of filter string with the original punctuation and spacing. The reason I want to do this is I want to change some words and put it back together as it was originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you eliminate the original punctuation, there's no way to turn it back automatically.

The only way is not to use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`.

An alternative solution may be to iterate through the string and, for each char, check if it belongs to your character set.
If yes, add the char to a list and the substring to another list (you may use `NSMutableArray` class).
This way, for example, you know that the punctuation char between the first and the second substring is the first character in your list of separators.

Answer (score 8):

A more robust way to split by words is to use string enumeration.  A space is not always the delimiter and not all languages delimit spaces anyway (e.g. Japanese).

```
NSString * string = @" \n word1!    word2,%$?'/word3.word4   ";

[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)
                           options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                        usingBlock:
 ^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
     NSLog(@"Substring: '%@'", substring);
 }];

 // Logs:
 // Substring: 'word1'
 // Substring: 'word2'
 // Substring: 'word3'
 // Substring: 'word4'
```

Comment: but the values gone after finished this block because of declaration done in autorelease method ,what i have to do for holding the values ,i like to use the values outside the block

Comment: @KishoreKumar - Store `substring` in a `NSMutableArray` that you created outside of the block.

Comment: yes bro i have tried but my values gone when i was tried to use it @Robert   http://codepaste.net/7du7k6

Comment: check the link bro

Comment: did you checked my link ?

Comment: sorry its my fault :) @Robert

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *myString = @"Foo Bar Blah B..";
NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]
                    ];
NSString* string = [myWords componentsJoinedByString: @" "];
NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you determining which words need to be replaced? Instead of breaking it apart in the first place, perhaps using `-stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` would be more suitable.

Comment: I cannot use the -stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range: because I want to only filter out occurrences of a words when it is not included in a separate word. For instance, If class were one of my words, I would not want to replace it in "classic".

Comment: Use the spaces to your advantage. You could look for a string like `@" class "`. This method also allows for certain options when scanning strings.

Comment: Ok I see the problem. As @DavidDunham suggested, look into other API. `NSLinguisticTagger` may be incredibly helpful in dissecting strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pathArray `componentsJoinedByString:` method of the array class to rejoin the words:

```
NSString *orig = [words pathArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Comment: Yes, but all the words will be joined by spaces, not the original punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you may not be using the best API. If you're really worried about words, you should be using a word-based API. I'm a bit hazy on whether that would be `NSDataDetector` or something else. (I believe `NSRegularExpression` can deal with word boundaries in a smarter way.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac OS X 10.7+ or iOS 4+ you can use `NSRegularExpression`, The pattern to replace a word is: "\b *word* \b" - (no spaces around *word*) \b matches a word boundary. Look at methods `replaceMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:` and `stringByReplacingMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:`.

Under 10.6 pr earlier if you wish to use regular expressions you can wrap the regcomp/regexec C-based functions, they support word boundaries as well. However you may prefer to use one of the other Cocoa options mentioned in other answers for this simple case.