# NSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: how to separate WITH punctuation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I don't know how to describe the problem, but what I want is to separate the sentence for example:

> What is that? That is a dog, a little dog.

to components:

```
"What", "is", "that?", "That", "is", "a", "dog", "a", "little", "dog."
```

So it will have punctuations, the problem is some of the sentences do not have space, so like:

> What is that?That is a dog,a little dog.

Then if I separate with space, I will get "that?That" and "dog,a".

Is there any way to do this?

I was thinking of having two passes, one to use [[NSCharacterSet lettersCharacterSet] inverseSet], to get pure letters (ie. words), then use `lettersCharacterSet` as separator to get all the spaces and punctuations, append each of the spaces/punctuation to each of the words in the 1st pass, not sure if it works?

Comment: "not sure if it works", why don't you try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go...

```
 NSMutableCharacterSet *seperatorSet = [NSMutableCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
 [seperatorSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet punctuationCharacterSet]];
 NSMutableArray *words = [[@"What is that?That is a dog,a little dog." componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:seperatorSet] mutableCopy];
```

Courtesy to this question [Split NSString into words, then rejoin it into original form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8597263/1042240)...